# connect virtual NICs to LAN on Windows

Tags: networking, mac, network-adapter

How can I add multiple virtual network interface cards on Windows 10 and connect them to local network using one physical network interface card?

In my use case I need to concurrently use multiple public ip addresses on one computer. My ISP's DHCP server assigns one public ip to each mac address connected to their network.
One solution is to get switch, NIC with multiple ports and physically connect multiple network cables to the computer. Such approach would however be messy and unnecessary because only one device would be actually connected to switch. Hence I would prefer using virtual NICs each with different MAC.

I tried Microsoft KM-TEST loopback adapter and openvpn's TAP-Windows adapter but I never got it actually connected to local network. It only shows "unidentified network"

Comment: I’m not aware of an easy way to achieve MACVLAN on Windows. However, I found a question that essentially asks the same and has a solution.

Comment: not sure whether I'm missing some salient point here... but that's what a router is usually for... one ISP, one public IP Address, NAT & private IP addresses inside that. MAC addresses do not cross borders.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I will test it as soon as I get computer with windows pro and NIC which allows me to change its MAC.